# How can I inject mocks into spring security classes

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using @PreAuthorize to secure a web request

```
@PreAuthorize("(@assessmentAuthService.canViewAssessment(#id))")
```

AssessmentAuthService is created automatically by spring, but I need to inject a mock object into it from my unit test.

```
private final AssessmentService assessmentService;

@Inject
public AssessmentAuthorizationServiceImpl(AssessmentService assessmentService) {
    this.assessmentService = assessmentService;
}
```

This is because I want assessmentService.getById(assessmentId) to return a mocked object.
I already tried setting it with this but it doesn't work:

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(assessmentAuthorizationService,
                             "assessmentService", mockAssessmentService);
```

Comment: And how does your unit test look like?

Comment: That's easier enough to do with something like mockito. What mocking framework are you using and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to inject a mock into AssessmentAuthorizationService with ReflectionTestUtils.setField but I didn't realize that spring beans are proxies.  I had to use this method to unwrap the proxy before I set the field.

```
class TestUtils {

  ...

public static Object unwrapService(Object service) throws Exception {
  final boolean aopProxy = AopUtils.isAopProxy(service);
  final boolean instanceCheck = service instanceof Advised;
  if (aopProxy && instanceCheck) {
    Object target = ((Advised) service).getTargetSource().getTarget();
    return target;
  }
return null;
}
}
```

After I did that it worked. I could set the field to a mock and the define the behavior that I wanted.

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(TestUtil.unwrapService(assessmentAuthorizationService),
                             "assessmentService", mockAssessmentService);
when(mockAssessmentService.getById(eq(2L))).thenReturn(Optional.of(assessment));
```